# How can I increase the volume when recording an audio in React Native expo-Audio?

Tags: react-native, volume, expo-av

I'm trying to record an audio with React Native expo-av but for some reason, the audio is coming out like if I was in a call. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to the function that handles recording playback, before (I'm assuming) you load the sound. E.g:

```
await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
  allowsRecordingIOS: false,

});
```

Source: https://forums.expo.io/t/try-to-use-expo-audio-ios-play-with-receiver-but-not-speaker/699/13

Comment: One year later, and it saved me! :P